# Не работает подписка на кириллические тэги

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, метки

Если попробовать подписаться на email-рассылку по тэгу, например [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), то подписываешься на самом деле на сайт целиком.

Comment: RSS нормальный, можно его юзать.

Comment: Ого. Кто-то пользуется email-рассылками.

Comment: Ну, для подписок - RSS самое то. А вот что уведомления о комментариях в вопросах, где ты отметился, не приходят на почту - печально :(

Comment: я пользовался e-mail рассылками на хеш-коде. Сейчас я тут на что-то подписался, а нихрена не приходит ничего! и  уж даже забыл о сообществе. лишь вот по рабочей надобности вспомнил.

Comment: Апнул. Недавно наткнулся на тот же баг.